# How to move a block into another block

Tags: twig, shopware6

Within [`@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig`](https://github.com/shopware/storefront/blob/trunk/Resources/views/storefront/base.html.twig) the blocks `base_header` and `base_navigation` are defined. I would like t move `base_navigation` into `base_header` to achieve a markup like this:

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-main">
        <!-- base_header_inner -->
    </div>
    <div class="nav-main">
        <!-- base_navigation_inner -->
    </div>
</header>
```

I have already tried the following:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}

{% block base_header %}
    <header>
        <div class="header-main">
            {% block base_header_inner %}
                {{ parent() }}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        {% block base_navigation %}
            {{ parent() }}
        {% endblock %}
    </header>
{% endblock %}
```

But instead of moving it it simply creates a new navigation within the header but keeps the original one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can empty the block in your twig file and load the original block with the block function (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/block.html)

Your file then looks something like this:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}

{% block base_header %}
    <header class="header-main">
        {% block base_header_inner %}
            <div class="container">
                {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/header/header.html.twig' %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {{ block('base_navigation', '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig') }}
    </header>
{% endblock %}

{% block base_navigation %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Nice I was not aware of this function. I already tried to empty it in my example from above but then I ran into the error that is already initialized.